# How to call oracle merge into from shell script

Tags: oracle, shell

I have one merge into statement and I'd like to execute it from shell script. Below is the merge into script.

```
    MERGE INTO TESTA t USING TESTA_TEMP s ON
(
  t.WAFER_ID = s.WAFER_ID
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    t.bin1 = s.bin1 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (
      id,
      bin1,
      wafer_id
    )
    VALUES
    (
      s.id,
      s.bin1,
      s.wafer_id
    );
```

It is working fine if I execute this in `sql plus manually. It shows below in the console.

```
4 rows merged.

SQL>
```

However, when I move this code in a shell script below, it won't work. Execute the shell script nothing happened, the console just shows the execution of shell script but never end.

```
#！/bin/sh
sqlplus -s user/pwd@sid <<END
SET serveroutput ON;
BEGIN
MERGE INTO TESTA t USING TESTA_TEMP s ON
(
  t.WAFER_ID = s.WAFER_ID
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    t.bin1 = s.bin1 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (
      id,
      bin1,
      wafer_id
    )
    VALUES
    (
      s.id,
      s.bin1,
      s.wafer_id
    );
END;
/
END
```

I have also tried to replace this merge into statement with a simple inert statement, that was working. So is there any limitation call such merge into statement in a shell script? Anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#！/bin/sh
sqlplus -s user/pwd@sid <<EOF
set feed on
set pages 0
MERGE INTO TESTA t USING TESTA_TEMP s ON
(
  t.WAFER_ID = s.WAFER_ID
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET
    t.bin1 = s.bin1 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (
      id,
      bin1,
      wafer_id
    )
    VALUES
    (
      s.id,
      s.bin1,
      s.wafer_id
    );
exit
EOF
```

Comment: @vincent: The problem was with your PLSQL code block. You cannot just call SQL statements inside it, you have to use dynamic SQL. For example: `execute immediate 'insert into ...';`. In your case you could just simply use SQL*PLUS to execute the merge statement. :)